# Can depth of an integral domain increase if you localise at a prime ideal?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an integral domain of finite type over a field $k$. Let $\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathfrak{q}$ be two prime ideals in A. Is it possible for $\text{depth}\,A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ to be greater than $\text{depth}\,A_{\mathfrak{q}}$?

Comment: What have you tried.. please share your difficulty..

Comment: If $\text{depth} A_{\mathfrak{p}}=1$, then we can see that any nonzero divisor in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a nonzero divisor in $A_{\mathfrak{q}}$ as well and therefore $\text{depth}A_{\mathfrak{q}}\geq 1$. I tried to induct after this, but for that I will need a prime element in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.